# Cant compile simple recorder

Tags: cmake, qt4

Hi people  i have recently been trying to install simple recorder on Centos 7 , but when i am a bout to run the ./simple-build- and install it starts to make it but appears this code about pulse audio
please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed9pG.png)

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Link to the **image of actual question**? Nice move! Seriously, [edit] your question and include all related information **as text**, not as links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont worry i already solved it , i was trying to install simple recorder , i have installed it now through a rpm , but i was following the instructions here https://www.linuxhelp.com/record-programs-simple-screen-recorder/ 
and i could not install it because of the error that is in the link image